# MAMP does not render fonts. Why?

Tags: fonts, mamp, mamp-pro

I literally copy-pasted the W3school example:

```
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sofia' rel='stylesheet'>
  <style>
  body {
    font-family: 'Sofia';font-size: 22px;
  }
  </style>
```

I checked Chrome console. There is a body tag. It has a font-family: Sofia. There is no other font-family rule to compete with it, whatsoever.

I checked the URL. It works, it has the woff2 to the font.

The font does not render on MAMP localhost frontend. Why does it not render?

Comment: Have a look in your network tab, to see if the asset loads are working (2xx response code). The link in your code loads more CSS, which in turn has more things to load.